# Añadir evento Onclick a Marker Mapbox Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as turf from 'turf';
// import * as bearing from 'turf-bearing';
import { MapService } from '../map.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.sass']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private servimapa: MapService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildMap();
  }

  private buildMap() {

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyNTgiLCJhIjoiY2ptNjQyN3ZjMHRydTN2cG9ybW9uMGVzOSJ9.LnduR5yIGHqGHGOEN7TlYw';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mar58/cjmhifftebj1m2rmql0kntkgb',
      center: [3.189744, 35.839860],
      zoom: 3.4,
      maxZoom: 5,
      minZomm: 2

    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

    const destinos =  {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-1.8585905869460078, 38.95939622270333]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Albacete',
            price: '600$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#6495ED',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-3.785098671342695, 40.350739864455846]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Madrid',
            price: '600$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#3bb2d0',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-4.108992254186973, 38.69287335431213]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Puertollano',
            price: '10$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#3bb2d0',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [12.52267330310275, 41.887991570175956]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Italia',
            price: '600$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#3bb2d0',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [139.78208123295104, 35.750342198794684]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Tokyo',
            price: '2600$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#3bb2d0',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [79.04970049922537, 21.16986187785818]
          },
          properties: {
            title: 'Indonesia',
            price: '1600$',
            image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8604/15769066303_3e4dcce464_n.jpg',
            'marker-color': '#3bb2d0',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'rocket-15'
          }
        },
      ]
    };



    map.on('load', function () {

      map.addSource('destinos', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: destinos
      });

      map.addLayer({
        id: 'destinos',
        source: 'destinos',
        interactive: true,
        type: 'symbol',
        // layout: {
        //   'icon-image':  'marker-15',
        //   'icon-size': 1

        // },

      });



      destinos.features.forEach(function(marker) {

        let popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: false, offset: [0, -15]})
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '<h3> <p> <strong>' + marker.properties.price + '</strong></p><img src="'
        + marker.properties.image + '" class="img-responsive" alt="">')
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates);

        // create a DOM element for the marker
        // add marker to map

        let marca =new mapboxgl.Marker()
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .setPopup(popup)
            .addTo(map);

       marca.on('click', function(){console.log('hola')});

      );

      map.on('mouseenter', 'destinos', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });

      map.on('mouseleave', 'destinos', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      });

    });


    });



  }

}
```

[image]
Hola buenas. Estoy intentando añadir una serie de marcadores en mapBox -gl. Dispongo de un geoJSON de nombre destinos el cual recorro y añado los Makers, también les inserto popup. Hasta ahí todo correcto. Mi problema esque no consigo añadir el evento onclick al marcador. Estoy en Angular6. He visto que mapBox Leaflet si hace el evento pero no me gustaría usarlo hasta ultimo recurso

Comment: Puedes poner el código como texto? Como una imagen es complicado copiarlo en una prueba para ver que falla. Te lo decimos a cada pregunta que haces pero no nos ayudas a ayudarte :(

Comment: SI perdona, siempre se me olvida

Comment: Qué versión de mapbox estás usando? La opción de añadir un "on click" a los Marker no estaba hace un año

Comment: <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

Comment: la 0.49 segun los script que me proporciona el MapboxStudio

Answer (score 0):

Esto funcionó para mi.

```
let el = document.createElement('div');
/* Asignando un `id` unico a tu marcador. */
el.id = 'idUnico'

let marcador = new Mapboxgl.Marker(el,{
              draggable: false 
              })
              .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
              .setPopup(popup)
              .addTo(map);
   
marcador.getElement()
.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('le di click al marcador ', marcador);
});
```